# Best practices for requesting file system in HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, html5-filesystem

I wonder what is more appropriate from technical point of view: to request file system (via `window.requestFileSystem` or `window.webkitRequestFileSystem` etc.) once and then work with reference to filesystem provided in callback or, may be, rerequest file system each time it is needed.

In other words, can I be sure  that during the session if filesystem had been successfully requested once, it hardly will be needed to be rerequested?

**UPD:**
For those who vote for closing. I'm not asking about any personal opinion on which one is nicer, I wonder are there any technical limitations and peculiarities one should be warned before choosing first or second approach.

Comment: Your question starts with "what is considered better". That's so broad, that it is opinion based. Your further explanation suggests that it is possible to reformulate your question to concern a more concrete issue. Perhaps if you try that people won't vote to close as "opinion-based" or "too broad".

Comment: @BartoszKP - I've rewritten initial phrase in order not to confuse people.

Comment: Looks better, however "what is more appropriate from technical point of view" is still vague and subjective. I won't vote on this any more, however there are 4 votes currently, so one more and your question gets closed.

Comment: @BartoszKP, well, honestly, it is a conundrum to me how this can be voted to be closed - for example this question is way less technical  - http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/213125/returning-multiple-values-in-javascript

Comment: 1) This is another site, I don't know their question policy. 2) The question you've linked IS more technical :| It starts with code example, and asks about particular reasons not to do something demonstrated concretely in the *code*. Whereas your question starts with the word "appropriate" which in general has connotation with subjectiveness. That's why I've suggested to reformulate your question not to start with this term, but something more concrete.

Comment: Have you found any answers for this? By the way, I agree that this a valid question.